# How to avoid multiple AJAX calls after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a text field in which I respond to typing by checking the database for the number of matches, but I don't want to pummel the database with too many queries for no reason if the user types several characters quickly.

Searching the web, the advice seems to be to wrap it all in `setTimeout()`, but I apparently don't understand how to use it properly. Here is my code at the moment:

```js
$(".qs-text").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.get("ajax_request.php?req=Quicksearch&qs=" + $(".qs-text").val(), function(data) {
        $('.qs-hits').text(data);
      });
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('.qs-hits').text('-');
  }
});
```

It does wait 500ms, and at the end of the timeout period, it does use the final state of the field in the request - good.

However then it sends multiple identical requests (one for every character I typed) instead of just one. That defeats the purpose of having the timeout in the first place. I can almost see why the code would do that, since the `keyup` event fires every time, but I have no idea how to solve it. There are other questions whose titles sound like what I'm asking, but every one I've read is different enough that I can't quite apply any of them to my case.

Comment: you missed the most crucial part of a debounce: canceling the previous timeout on each creation of a new timeout

Comment: "debouncing" as this is known is quite a subtle thing - I'd recommend looking at utility libraries like lodash or underscore which supply their own debounce functions

Comment: Wrapping it *all* in a setTimeout just delays it all.  That's just the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need cancel timeout when create a new.

```js
var timeout = null;
$(".qs-text").keyup(function() {
  if(timeout != null) clearTimeout(timeout);
  if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { $.get("ajax_request.php?req=Quicksearch&qs="+$(".qs-text").val(), function(data) {
      $('.qs-hits').text(data);
    }); },500);
  } else {
    $('.qs-hits').text('-');
  }
});
```

Comment: Next step could be to compare what you're about to send with what you last sent - eg if user presses a key then backspaces that key, no need to resend.

Comment: Yeah, in the truth have various verification that u need do in this cases, it's up to the op to decide what to do.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah, that would be even more precise, but it doesn't need to catch edge cases like that - the basic anti-pummeling is good enough. I did add encodeURIComponent() after noticing issues with punctuation.

Comment: @naxsi yes, that's what I meant, OP's next step - no change to your code.

Answer (score 1):

We usually store the timeout in variable and then clear it conditionally when call a new one. However for large web application, I suggest using web sockets for such subsequent calls for real-time experience

```
var timer;
$(".qs-text").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $.get("ajax_request.php?req=Quicksearch&qs=" + $(".qs-text").val(), function(data) {
            $('.qs-hits').text(data);
        });
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('.qs-hits').text('-');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like lodash for debouncing, so you can do something like this

```
$(".qs-text").keyup(function() {  

   _.debounce(()=> {
     $.get("ajax_request.php?req=Quicksearch&qs="+$(".qs-text").val(), function(data) {
      $('.qs-hits').text(data);
    })
   }, 500)
  

});
```

for more info, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce